# What spells, enchantments and charms do we know were taught in the first year of Hogwart's curriculum?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, magical-theory, spells

I'm about to write a fanfiction based in the Harry Potter universe, but I want it to be strictly canonical.

A lot of fanfics invent spells of their own similar to Eliezer Yudowsky's satirical *Fixus Everythingus* in Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality.

These always make stories seem unrealistic and overly contrived, and I don't want that to happen, so I only want to use spells that J. K. Rowling invented and used in the Harry Potter series.

What magical **spells**, **enchantments** and **charms** are taught in the first-year Hogwart's curriculum at the time that Harry was first-year? <sub>(eg it may have been different under Umbridge).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for respecting the source material in your fanfiction. I've read a few doozies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hogwart's first year curriculum involves the following textbooks:

> COURSE BOOKS
>   All students should have a copy of each of the following:
>
> - **The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1)** by Miranda Goshawk
> - **A History of Magic** by Bathilda Bagshot
> - **Magical Theory** by Adalbert Waffling
> - **A Beginners’ Guide to Transfiguration** by Emeric Switch
> - **One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi** by Phyllida Spore
> - **Magical Drafts and Potions** by Arsenius Jigger
> - **Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them** by Newt Scamander
> - **The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection** by Quentin Trimble
>
> <sub>(*Harry Potter and Philospher's Stone, Chapter 5* - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/harrys-school-list))</sub>

Out of these textbooks, we only know of three of them to have contained spells.

### **The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1)**

[image]

### **The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection**

[image]

### **A Beginners’ Guide to Transfiguration**

> Incomplete Transfigurations are difficult to put right, but you must attempt to do so. Leaving the head of a rabbit on a footstool is irresponsible and dangerous. Say **‘Reparifarge!’** and the object or creature should return to its natural state.
>   <sub>(*Pottermore*)</sub>

---

### So the spells that we know of are:

<sub>Incantations taken from *Pottermore* and *Wonderbook: Book of Spells*

Note: The wand gestures in *Wonderbook: Book of Spells* differ from those found on *Pottermore* (probably due to simplification)</sub>

- Fire-Making Spell (Incendio)
- Levitation Charm (Wingardium Leviosa)
- Locking Spell (Colloportus)
- Mending Charm (Reparo)
- Severing Charm (Diffindo)
- Softening Charm (Spongify)
- Unlocking Spell (Alohomora)
- Curse of the Bogies (Mucus Ad Nauseam)
- Green Sparks (--)
- Knockback Jinx (Flipendo)
- Red Sparks (--)
- Smokescreen Spell (Fumos)
- Wand-Extinguishing Charm (Nox)
- Wand-Lighting Charm (Lumos)
- Un-Transfiguration spell? (Reparifarge)

<sub>Note: Non-canon sources give us incantations for wand sparks.

Green Sparks - Verdimillious (Video Games), Verdillious (Trading Card Game)

Red Sparks - Periculum (Movies), Vermillious (Video Games, Trading Card Game)</sub>

Comment: Was Alohomora a first-year spell?

Comment: @MathiasFoster Pottermore places it in *Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1)*, so yes. A possible explanation to the significance of Hermione knowing it is that it is the last spell listed in that book.

Comment: @MathiasFoster The only spells that this list appears to be missing is most of the transfiguration spells, and that is only due to lack of canon information. (Outside of canon, you can find many transfiguration spells in the video games and Trading Cards.)

Comment: Perfect! +1 (btw: I was always happy) :)

Comment: @MathiasFoster I've slightly updated my answer. Feel free to ask about the other Hogwarts year curriculums.

Comment: @ibid thy will be done :) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122505/what-spells-enchantments-and-charms-do-we-know-were-taught-in-the-second-year-o

Comment: I think the animation charm needs to be added as the charms final includes making a pineapple dance across a table.

Comment: What is the source for the images in this answer?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - The images are screenshots from Pottermore's old website. YMMV as to their canonicity.