# What spells, enchantments, charms and potions do we know were taught in the second year of Hogwart's curriculum?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, hogwarts, spells

A [follow-up question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/what-spells-enchantments-and-charms-do-we-know-were-taught-in-the-first-year-of#comment295589_119584) to [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/what-spells-enchantments-and-charms-do-we-know-were-taught-in-the-first-year-of) covering the first year.

As stated in the previous question, I'm writing a strictly canonical fanfic, and I don't want to make up spells as a *deus ex machina*, as this often makes seem overly contrived.

I would much rather work within the framework laid by J. K. Rowling in the Harry Potter series.

What magical spells, enchantments, charms and potions are taught in the second-year Hogwart's curriculum at the time that Harry was second-year?

Comment: Is this within the guidelines? It seems like you're asking for a list. Can you rewrite it to avoid that?

Comment: @rosesunhill well defined lists are fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Spells

Once again we can look at their list of course books.

> SECOND-YEAR STUDENTS WILL REQUIRE:

> - **The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 2** by Miranda Goshawk

- **Break with a Banshee** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Gadding with Ghouls** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Holidays with Hags** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Travels with Trolls** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Voyages with Vampires** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Wanderings with Werewolves** by Gilderoy Lockhart
- **Year with the Yeti** by Gilderoy Lockhart

> <sub>(*Harry Potter and Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 4*)</sub>

Only one of these is a spellbook.
[image]

We can also assume that the following first year books were still used:

> **A History of Magic** by Bathilda Bagshot
> **Magical Theory** by Adalbert Waffling
> **A Beginners’ Guide to Transfiguration** by Emeric Switch
> **One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi** by Phyllida Spore
> **Magical Drafts and Potions** by Arsenius Jigger
> **Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them** by Newt Scamander
> <sub>[text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/harrys-school-list)</sub>

Of these, the only spell that we know of is "Reparifarge!" from *A Beginners’ Guide to Transfiguration*.

> Incomplete Transfigurations are difficult to put right, but you must attempt to do so. Leaving the head of a rabbit on a footstool is irresponsible and dangerous. Say **‘Reparifarge!’** and the object or creature should return to its natural state.
> <sub>(*Pottermore*)</sub>

There is still one spell that Lockhart teaches (which may be found in his books) - "Peskipiksi Pesternomi" - Note that this probably isn't even a real spell. However, it may have been an attempt at the Freezing Charm.

> “Come on now — round them up, round them up, they’re only pixies,” Lockhart shouted.
> He rolled up his sleeves, brandished his wand, and bellowed, “**Peskipiksi Pesternomi**!”
> <sub>(*Harry Potter and Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 6* - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/pesky-pixies))</sub>

---

### Potions

The only potions textbook that second year students have is *Magical Drafts and Potions*. Bear in mind that they use this same textbook until sixth year, so not all of these are necessarily second year potions.

[image]

- Antidote to Common Poisons
- Cure for Boils (first years)
- Forgetfulness Potion (first years)
- Herbicide
- Sleeping Draught (Hermione makes one in book two)
- Swelling Solution (second years)
- Wideye or Awakening Potion

In addition, we also know that they learned about **Hair Raising Potions**.

> Snape had given them so much homework, Harry thought he was likely to be in the sixth year before he finished it. Ron was just saying he wished he had asked Hermione how many rat tails you were supposed to add to a **Hair Raising Potion** when an angry outburst from the floor above reached their ears.
> <sub>(*Harry Potter and Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 13*)</sub>

---

### So the spells and potions that we know of are:

**Spells**

<sub>Incantations taken from *Pottermore* and *Wonderbook: Book of Spells*

Note: The wand gestures in *Wonderbook: Book of Spells* differ from those found on *Pottermore* (probably due to simplification)</sub>

- Dancing Feet Spell (Tarantellegra)
- Disarming Charm (Expelliarmus)
- Engorgement Charm (Engorgio)
- Freezing Charm (Immobulus)
- General Counter-Spell (Finite Incantatem)
- Memory Charm (Obliviate) <sub>Probably students only learn *about* this spell</sub>
- Tickling Charm (Rictusempra)
- Lockhart's™ Pixie Rounding-up Charm? (Peskipiksi Pesternomi)
- Un-Transfiguration spell? (Reparifarge) <sub>Possibly taught in previous year</sub>

**Potions**

- Swelling Solution
- Hair Raising Potion
- Sleeping Draught <sub>Safe to assume, but not conclusive</sub>
- Antidote to Common Poisons <sub>Possibly taught in a different year</sub>
- Herbicide <sub>Possibly taught in a different year</sub>
- Wideye or Awakening Potion <sub>Possibly taught in a different year</sub>

Comment: @DavidW - The list was literally a transcription of an image, so it would make no sense to add something onto the list which isn't in the image. Why'd you approve the suggested edit?

Comment: Because I looked it up, and found it mentioned.  That list is a summary not a transcription, so it made sense to include it.

Comment: @DavidW - The list is a summary of the evidence presented at the beginning of the answer. That particular part was a transcription of the image. Post authors get notified about suggested edits, so in the future don't be so trigger happy to approve them yourself unless the OP never logs in any more.