# What was taught in the third year of Hogwart's curriculum?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, magical-theory, spells

*A series of questions covering each year of Hogwarts curriculum, also see:*

- *[First year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116900/what-spells-enchantments-and-charms-do-we-know-were-taught-in-the-first-year-of)*
- *[Second year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122505/what-spells-enchantments-charms-and-potions-do-we-know-were-taught-in-the-seco)*

---

As stated in the previous questions, I'm writing a fanfiction based in the world created by JKR, and therefore only using the same spells, enchantments, charms and potions created in this use (because it seriously sucks a fanfic author can only think of *Fixus Everythingus* in order to clear an impasse).

What magical spells, enchantments, charms and potions are taught in the third-year Hogwart's curriculum at the time that Harry was third-year?

Comment: Is this fanfiction online? A link might be appreciated by now. :)

Comment: @ibid no, it's not. I'm thinking of releasing it complete... because I hate waiting for updates, and (imagine that) other people do too.

Comment: Time travel for beginners!

Comment: @PeterPeter - Closest I ever came to writing HP fanfiction is probably [my deleted answer to this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117720). (Which you obviously won't be able to see without reaching 10k.)

Comment: @ibid consider pasting it into a [bin](http://pastebin.ca/) for us non-10k-ers? Sounds like it could be worth reading...

Comment: @PeterPeter - [screenshots](http://m.imgur.com/a/CJqzn) (from my phone, as my internet is down for a couple of hours today.)

Comment: @PeterPeter - I am open for suggestions as to how to improve it or how to make it into an actual flyer to append to my other answer.

Comment: Would you like us to mention the resisting dark creatures spells that they were taught in DADA as well??

Comment: @Bellerephon if they were spells taught in year 3... yup!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Once again we'll start with the book list (never shown in list form, but can be surmised from passage):

> Harry pulled his booklist out of his pocket and consulted it for the
>   first time. **The Monster Book of Monsters** was listed as the required book
>   for Care of Magical Creatures.
>   
>   "Yes," said Harry, looking down his booklist, "I need **Unfogging the Future by Cassandra Vablatsky**."
>   "Ah, starting Divination, are you?" said the manager, stripping off his
>   gloves and leading Harry into the back of the shop, where there was a
>   corner devoted to fortune-telling.
>   
>   "Anything else?" he said.
>   "Yes," said Harry, tearing his eyes away from the dog's and dazedly
>   consulting his booklist. "Er -- I need **Intermediate Transfiguration** and
>   **The Standard Book of Spells, Grade Three.**"
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 4*)</sub>

Of course, some of these books are only for electives. We see Hermione (who has more classes) with other books. (But then knowing Hermione, we don't know if these were actually required textbooks or merely just "light reading".)

> They hurried down to the Gryffindor common room, which was half-empty, and joined Hermione, who was sitting alone, reading a book called **Ancient Runes Made Easy**.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 14*)</sub>
>
> "Why don't you just drop a couple of subjects?" Harry asked, watching her lifting books as she searched for her **rune dictionary**.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 12*)</sub>
>
> Only one person wasn't joining in the festivities. Hermione, incredibly,
>   was sitting in a corner, attempting to read an enormous book entitled
>   **Home Life and Social Habits of British Muggles**.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 13*)</sub>
>
> "Is there any point asking how you're going to sit for two exams at
>   once?" said Harry.
>   "No," said Hermione shortly. "Have either of you seen my copy of
>   **Numerology and Gramatica**?"
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 16*)</sub>

In addition, there appears to have been some unnamed textbook for Defense against the Dark Arts. ([Called *The Essential Defence Against the Dark Arts* in the movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FOL7.jpg).)

> Professor Lupin wasn't there when they arrived at his first Defense Against the Dark Arts lesson. They all sat down, took out their **books**, quills, and parchment, and were talking when he finally entered the room.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 7*)</sub>
>
> "You are easily satisfied. Lupin is hardly overtaxing you -- I ,Would expect first years to be able to deal with Red Caps and grindylows. Today we shall discuss --"
>   Harry watched him flick through the **textbook**, to the very back chapter, which he must know they hadn't covered.
>   "Werewolves," said Snape.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 9*)</sub>

Adding this to the books presumably carried over from previous years we have.

> New core books
>   **Intermediate Transfiguration**
>   **The Standard Book of Spells, Grade Three** by Miranda Goshawk
>   **Defense Against the Dark Arts textbook (Untitled)**
>
> New electives
>   **The Monster Book of Monsters** (Care of Magical Creatures)
>   **Unfogging the Future** by Cassandra Vablatsky (Divination)
>   **Ancient Runes Made Easy** (Ancient Runes?)
>   **rune dictionary** (Ancient Runes?)
>   **Numerology and Gramatica** (Arithmancy)
>   **Home Life and Social Habits of British Muggles** by Wilhelm Wigworthy (Muggle Studies?)
>
> Old books
>   **A History of Magic** by Bathilda Bagshot
>   **Magical Theory** by Adalbert Waffling
>   **One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi** by Phyllida Spore
>   **Magical Drafts and Potions** by Arsenius Jigger
>   **Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them** by Newt Scamander

---

## Sadly no Pottermore pictures for any of these new books as the Pottermore team apparently got bored halfway through the second book. (Something that may happen to your fanfic.)

We can still go through each book and analyze what we know of its contents.

- **Intermediate Transfiguration** (No info about the book, so info about the class)

  > - **Animagi**
  >
  >   > He hardly heard what Professor McGonagall was telling them about **Animagi** (wizards who could transform at will into animals), and wasn't even watching when she transformed herself in front of their eyes into a tabby cat with spectacle markings around her eyes.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 6*)</sub>
  > - **turning a teapot into a tortoise**
  >
  >   > The third years emerged from Transfiguration at lunchtime on Monday, limp and ashen-faced, comparing results and bemoaning the difficulty of the tasks they had been set, which had included **turning a teapot into a tortoise**.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 16*)</sub>
- **The Standard Book of Spells, Grade Three** by Miranda Goshawk

  > **Cheering Charms**
  >
  > > “Come along, quickly, wands out, we’re experimenting with **Cheering Charms** today, we’ve already divided into pairs —”
  > >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 15*)</sub>
- **Defense Against the Dark Arts textbook (Untitled)**

  > - **Boggart banishing spell**
  >
  >   > “The charm that repels a boggart is simple, yet it requires force of mind. You see, the thing that really finishes a boggart is laughter. What you need to do is force it to assume a shape that you find amusing.
  >   >     “We will practice the charm without wands first. After me, please . . . **Riddikulus**!”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 7*)</sub>
  >
  > **Other curriculum in this book.** (But not spells)
  >
  > - **Boggarts**
  > - **Red Caps**
  >
  >   > After **boggarts**, they studied **Red Caps**, nasty little goblinlike creatures that lurked wherever there had been bloodshed: in the dungeons of castles and the potholes of deserted battlefields, waiting to bludgeon those who had gotten lost.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 8*)</sub>
  > - **Kappas**
  >
  >   > From Red Caps they moved on to **kappas**, creepy water-dwellers that looked like scaly monkeys, with webbed hands itching to strangle unwitting waders in their ponds.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 8*)</sub>
  > - **Grindylows**
  >
  >   > “Water demon,” said Lupin, surveying the **grindylow** thoughtfully. “We shouldn’t have much difficulty with him, not after the kappas. The trick is to break his grip. You notice the abnormally long fingers? Strong, but very brittle.”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 8*)</sub>
  > - **Hinkpunks**
  > - **Werewolves**
  >
  >   > “But, sir,” said Hermione, seemingly unable to restrain herself, “we’re not supposed to do **werewolves** yet, we’re due to start **hinkypunks** —”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 9*)</sub>
  > - **Vampires**
  >
  >   > “Er — not now — I was going to go to the library and do that **vampire** essay for Lupin —”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 14*)</sub>
- **The Monster Book of Monsters**

  > - **Hippogriffs**
  >
  >   > “**Hippogriffs**!” Hagrid roared happily, waving a hand at them. “Beau’iful, aren’ they?”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 6*)</sub>
  > - **Flobberworms**
  >
  >   > They were now spending lesson after lesson learning how to look after **flobberworms**, which had to be some of the most boring creatures in existence.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 8*)</sub>
  > - **Salamanders**
  >
  >   > The last thing anyone felt like doing was spending two hours on the grounds on a raw January morning, but Hagrid had provided a bonfire full of **salamanders** for their enjoyment, and they spent an unusually good lesson collecting dry wood and leaves to keep the fire blazing while the flame-loving lizards scampered up and down the crumbling, white-hot logs.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 12*)</sub>
- **Unfogging the Future** by Cassandra Vablatsky (Divination)

  > No Spells, but book is known to cover:
  >
  > - **Palmistry**
  > - **Crystal Balls**
  > - **Bird Entrails**
  >
  >   > “Here you are,” said the manager, who had climbed a set of steps to take down a thick, black-bound book. “Unfogging the Future. Very good guide to all your basic fortune-telling methods — **palmistry, crystal balls, bird entrails** —”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 4*)</sub>
  > - **Reading tea leaves**
  >
  >   > “We will be covering the basic methods of Divination this year. The first term will be devoted to **reading the tea leaves**."
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 6*)</sub>
  > - **Fire omens**
  >
  >   > “In the second term,” Professor Trelawney went on, “we shall progress to the crystal ball — if we have finished with **fire omens**, that is."
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 6*)</sub>
- **Ancient Runes**

  > While we don't know much about this curriculum, [an excerpt of *Ancient Runes Made Easy*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYbDe.jpg) was released on the old jkrowling.com.
- **Muggle Studies**

  > **Electricity**
  >
  > > for a fuller understanding of what **electricity** is, see Home Life and Social Habits of British Muggles, Wilhelm Wigworthy, Little Red Books, 1987
  > >     <sub>(*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Chizpurfle*)</sub>
- **A History of Magic** by Bathilda Bagshot

  > **Flame Freezing Charm** (not necessarily taught, but part of required reading.)
  >
  > > The witch or wizard would perform a basic **Flame Freezing Charm** and then pretend to shriek with pain while enjoying a gentle, tickling sensation.
  > >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 1*)</sub>
- **Potions** (Presumably found in *Magical Drafts and Potions*.)

  > - **Shrinking Solutions**
  >
  >   > They were making a new potion today, a **Shrinking Solution**. Malfoy set up his cauldron right next to Harry and Ron, so that they were preparing their ingredients on the same table.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 7*)</sub>
  > - **Confusing Concoctions**
  >
  >   > Try as Harry might, he couldn’t get his **Confusing Concoction** to thicken, and Snape, standing watch with an air of vindictive pleasure, scribbled something that looked suspiciously like a zero onto his notes before moving away.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 16*)</sub>
  > - **Undetectable Poisons**
  >
  >   > "How's she doing it?" Ron muttered to Harry one evening as Harry sat finishing a nasty essay on **Undetectable Poisons** for Snape.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 12*)</sub>
- **Others**

  > - **Water Repelling Charm(?)** (Not necessarily taught this year, or even at all, considering Wood didn't know it, but it could have been Hermione reading ahead.)
  >
  >   > He handed them to her, and as the team watched in amazement, Hermione tapped them with her wand and said, “**Impervius**!”
  >   >     “There!” she said, handing them back to Harry. “**They’ll repel water**!”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 9*)</sub>
  > - **Useful Little Spell(?) Blowing Gum out-of-keyhole Charm(?)** (Also, maybe not part of the curriculum, but it definitely was taught.)
  >
  >   > “This is a useful little spell,” he told the class over his shoulder. “Please watch closely.”
  >   >     He raised the wand to shoulder height, said, “**Waddiwasi!**” and pointed it at Peeves.
  >   >     With the force of a bullet, **the wad of chewing gum shot out of the keyhole** and straight down Peeves’s left nostril; he whirled up-right and zoomed away, cursing.
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 7*)</sub>
  > - **Patronus Charm** (Harry is taught this, but it is made pretty clear that this is beyond even fifth year curriculum)
  >
  >   > “The spell I am going to try and teach you is highly advanced magic, Harry — well beyond Ordinary Wizarding Level. It is called the **Patronus Charm**.”
  >   >     <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 12*)</sub>

---

## So the spells, potions, creatures, and other topics that we know of are:

**Spells:**
Taught as part of curiculum

- Cheering Charms
- Boggart banishing spell (Riddikulus)
- turning a teapot into a tortoise spell
- Flame Freezing Charm

Taught outside of curriculum:

- Blowing Gum out-of-keyhole Charm(?) (Waddiwasi)
- Water Repelling Charm(?) (Impervius)
- Patronus Charm (Expecto Patronum)

**Potions:**

- Shrinking Solutions
- Confusing Concoctions
- Undetectable Poisons

**Creatures:**
Taught to everyone:

- Bogarts
- Red Caps
- Kappas
- Grindylows
- Hinkpunks
- Vampires
- Werewolves

Taught only to Care of Magical Creatures students:

- Hippogriffs
- Flobberworms
- Salamanders

**Topics:**
Taught to everyone:

- Animagi (Transfiguration)

Electives:

- Palmistry (Divination)
- Crystal Balls (Divination)
- Bird Entrails (Divination)
- Reading tea leaves (Divination)
- Fire omens (Divination)
- [This chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYbDe.jpg) (Ancient Runes)
- electricity (Muggle Studies)

Comment: And I still didn't hit the character limit. One of these day, one of these days...

Comment: I don't think Hermione's readings/learnings would be a reliable indicator of the actual curriculum at any given year. She's been known to do a lot of extra-curricular reading. She, muggle-born and raised, already confidently  knew how to cast a successful reparo charm to fix Harry's glasses while they were on the train to Hogwarts for their first year (according to the movie, anyway) - they hadn't even attended day 1 yet.

Answer (score 8):

### Classes

In the third year, students were able to select from a more diverse list of courses. **As a result, not all students shared the same curriculum**.

For example, Harry added only Divination and Care of Magical Creatures from the previous year.

> Most important of all, he had to buy his new schoolbooks, which would
>   include those for his two new subjects, Care of Magical Creatures and
>   Divination.

Hermione, on the other hand, had quite a few more:

> "Well, I'm taking more new subjects than you, aren't I?' said
>   Hermione. "Those are my books for Arithmancy, Care of Magical
>   Creatures, Divination, the Study of Ancient Runes, Muggle Studies --"

The courses offered were (elective courses in **bold**):

- Defense Against the Dark Arts
- Herbology
- Potions
- Charms
- Transfiguration
- History of Magic
- Astronomy
- **Ancient Runes**
- **Muggle Studies**
- **Care of Magical Creatures**
- **Divination**
- **Arithmancy**

Not all of these classes involved spells or potions.

### Potions

- Shrinking Solutions:

  > "Everyone gather 'round," said Snape, his black eyes glittering, and
  >   watch what happens to Longbottom's toad. If he has managed to produce
  >   a Shrinking Solution, it will shrink to a tadpole. If, as I don't
  >   doubt, he has done it wrong, his toad is likely to be poisoned."
- Confusing Concoctions

  > They had Potions that afternoon, which was an unqualified disaster.
  >   Try as Harry might, he couldn't get his Confusing Concoction to
  >   thicken, and Snape, standing watch with an air of vindictive pleasure,
  >   scribbled something that looked suspiciously like a zero onto his
  >   notes before moving away.

  The function of a Confusing Concoction may be explained in the fifth book, if it is the same as a Confusing Draft:

  > These plantes are moste efficacious in the inflaming of the braine,
  >   and are therefore much used in Confusing and Befuddlement Draughts,
  >   where the wizard is desirous of producing hot-headedness and
  >   recklessness ...
- Undetectable Poisons

  > "How's she doing it?" Ron muttered to Harry one evening as Harry sat
  >   finishing a nasty essay on Undetectable Poisons for Snape. Harry looked
  >   up. Hermione was barely visible behind a tottering pile of books.

### Spells

The main textbook is the *Standard Book of Spells, Grade 3*. 
According to [Potterwiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Standard_Book_of_Spells,_Grade_3)

> This is the first book in The Standard Book of Spells series whose
>   contents will not be viewable on Pottermore.

Also according to the wiki, the spells for the third year can be found in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (video game)*, but include the Patronus Charm. So they should perhaps be taken with a grain of salt. This is *not* canon, since it is all from the video game, and the textbook is not visible on Pottermore.

In any case, the spells are:

- Disarming Charm
- Draconifors Spell

  [Apparently](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Draconifors_Spell) this transfigures objects into dragons.
- Freezing Spell
- Lapifors Spell

  [Apparently](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Lapifors_Spell) this transfigures objects into rabbits.
- Lumos Duo Charm
- Mending Charm
- Seize and Pull Charm
- Snufflifors Spell

  [Apparently](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Snufflifors_Spell) this transfigures objects into mice.

The following spells are backed up by book quotes, and **are** canon.

Flitwick taught Cheering Charms:

> "You're late, boys!" said Professor Flitwick reprovingly as Harry
>   opened the classroom door. "Come along, quickly, wands out, we're
>   experimenting with Cheering Charms today, we've already divided into
>   pairs --"

Professor Lupin taught the Boggart-Banishing Spell:

> "The charm that repels a boggart is simple, yet it requires force of
>   mind. You see, the thing that really finishes a boggart is laughter.
>   What you need to do is force it to assume a shape that you find
>   amusing.
>
> "We will practice the charm without wands first. After me, please ...
>   Riddikulus!"

Technically, he also taught another spell:

> "This is a useful little spell, he told the class over his shoulder.
>   "Please watch closely." He raised the wand to shoulder height, said,
>   "Waddiwasi! "and pointed it at Peeves.

Comment: Submitted my answer. Let the voting war commence. (Not that these question receive much traffic eitherway.)